# Would zRam increase my computer's performance?

Tags: virtualization, zram

[This article](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html) says you can have increased performance in Linux with zRam (virtual swap compressed in RAM).

I have 4 GB of RAM , 2.93 GHz (Dual Core) & I use virtualization a lot (VMWare). Would it be helpful to my computer's performance to install zRam? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 as my host and a VMWare workstation for virtualization .

Comment: & how do i know that zRam is working or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using it on Oneiric and have not found any problem yet. You should give it a try, and see if the performance is better. Virtualization is one of their use cases. But bear in mind that to give that "extra memory" effect, pages are compressed, which requires cpu power.

To see if it is running, use `service zramswap status`

Comment: zramswap start/running

Comment: My question was it really work as it says

Comment: As i said, it depends of the use you give to vm's. If you use vm's to run cpu intensive tasks, the extra cpu power needed to compress the pages could not improve performance at all. In my system, i feel that it is a lot more responsible when the swap memory begins to be used.